# Firebase-Android, How to sync data when resume after connection lost?

Tags: android, firebase

My case is I connected to internet when login, then I turn off all connections and post some data (push + set). After that, I connect again but I see that new data is not sent to server.

How can I force data sync right after connection resumed

Note I used this from beginning:

```
Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
Firebase ref = new Firebase(apiUrl);
ref.keepSynced(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does this automatically. When a connection is lost, Firebase will continue to work offline firing events locally and working the the data persisted to the cache.

The local persistent cache has a size limit. When the cache hits the limit, the SDK will oust the least used data. Using `.keepSynced()` is just a way to ensure the data isn't purged from the cache.

Comment: Thank for your reply, but I waited for a long time but still don't see any new data send to database.

Comment: Can you detail step-by-step, what you're doing and what you're seeing? Because Firebase resyncs when the device regains its connection.

Comment: It randomly happens. I try as following step:
1. Login (connect internet)
2. Turn off connection
3. Call push + set to add new data
4. Turn on connection and wait.


I try 10 times, and lost 2 of them

Comment: Do you have any security rules written?

Comment: Yes. This is my rules in short https://gist.github.com/rickyngk/bee4dccfc655570e991d

Comment: Or you can also take a look at whole my project here https://github.com/rickyngk/pal (included full version of bolt file)

Comment: Note that it happens randomly with low probability. I run beta test in last week, and there's one user report.
I myself reproduce on my device, it got 2 this morning. But then dont happen anymore up to now

Comment: It sounds like a network issue, but it's impossible to tell. You'll probably get some more insight if you run Firebase with debug logging, by calling `Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)` before creating any Firebase reference.

Comment: Yep, I'll report more detail when I get it.

Comment: Hmm. It happens again and this is log
https://gist.github.com/rickyngk/b0e5c4216816fef89649

I try to save data to /posts/$key 4 times but lost all

Comment: A note: It happens when I minimize application and leave it inactive in some hours, then I resume it from recent app list.

Comment: Did you get a solution?
I'm going through this situation .. it's terrible, user losing all the work!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has same reason with [Firebase-Android, Fail to save data after long time idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384635/firebase-android-fail-to-save-data-after-long-time-idle)

Not really about "turn off all connections", let app idle for a long time then it happens.