# Firebase-Android, Fail to save data after long time idle

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

This question is relative to this issue [Firebase-Android, How to sync data when resume after connection lost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259016/firebase-android-how-to-sync-data-when-resume-after-connection-lost)

Step-by-step is:

- First I login using email method in Auth Activity
- In Timeline activity I add an record.

Everything looks good. But if I minimize app for about 24 hours, then resume application at timeline activity and add new record, I got error: "java.lang.Exception: Permission denied". I'm sure nothing wrong with new data, but:

```
path / {
    read() = true;
    write() = isSignedIn();
}
isSignedIn() = auth != null;
```

So I think that after long idle, maybe session was timeout.

Have you got same issue, and how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue by saving last login credential (email + password) then call login with email again when app resumed (onResume event of Activity)